# How to remove duplicate values from S3 bucket that gets populated by Glue Job

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, apache-spark, amazon-s3, aws-glue

I have a Glue job that exports data from a dynamoDB to S3.

But i did not enable any Glue Job bookmark. Now when i run a query in Athena, i see that there are duplicate data entries in S3.

Without duplicates :

```
select count(distinct(createdat)) from layer2sessions;
Result : 130
```

With Duplicates:

```
SELECT id, COUNT(id) 
FROM layer2sessions
GROUP BY id
HAVING COUNT(id) > 1; 
Result :

1   3c502774-85dd-4659-b9e9-57548   332
2   c3cc0893-a7fb-40fd-8642-8864f   498
3   42862b3b-0db2-4408-ac31-019a5   332
4   505ea15d-dd8c-44b1-86b5-7defe   2278
```

How can i correct this ? Can i delete the duplicates from S3 ? Or how about AWS Glue bookmarks? Does this help? Or can i create a table in Athena from another Athena query that gives distinct rows? And how do i stop the further reruns of the Glue job from adding any more duplicates to S3? PLease anyone has the answers?

Answer (score 0):

You can easily create new table from existing table in Athena.
Format mentioned you can chage as per your need

```
CREATE TABLE DB_NAME.table_name
WITH (
  format='TEXTFILE'
) AS
SELECT * FROM select distinct(createdat) from "DB"."layer2sessions";
```

[athena_ctas_support](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2018/10/athena_ctas_support/)

[athena-create-table-as](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/create-table-as.html)